# How can y use Tapestry component with String parameters?

Tags: java, tapestry

This is the code of my tapestry component : (it works)

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Property;
public class SimpleChart {
    @Property
    @Parameter(value="123")
    private String title;
}
```

But when I write "abc" instead of "123", It doesn't work anymore. I need to replace the number with a sentence. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html). You forgot the defaultPrefix :

```
@Parameter(defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL, value="abc")
```